# Does XFINITY allow web hosting?

Tags: web-hosting

I am running a website for updating my program and for getting information. I run it in my house, I looked at the ToS for XFINITY and it seems that it may not be allowed. am I allowed to run a website using XFINITY or AT&T?

Comment: Tried asking them?

Comment: If you run a website from in your house then expect to leave your computer (at least the motherboard and hard drive) on all day and night and expect a big electric bill. You're better off using a remote server and hosting from there

Comment: @Mike It is not that bad... I have a cr@p 10@d of commercial servers running; Dell 1750, 2950, R500, Compaq ProWorkstation, 3500, DEC, HP, SGI, Cobalt, Cubix (blade servers), and more running and my electric bill is about $100 a month.

Comment: only $100? that's dirt cheap.

Answer (score 4):

XFINITY no, in short...

> [Technical restrictions](http://www.xfinity.com/Corporate/Customers/Policies/HighSpeedInternetAUP.html)
>
> Use or run dedicated, stand-alone equipment or servers from the
>   Premises that provide network content or any other services to anyone
>   outside of your Premises local area network (“Premises LAN”), also
>   commonly referred to as public services or servers. Examples of
>   prohibited equipment and servers include, but are not limited to,
>   email, web hosting, file sharing, and proxy services and servers;

As for AT&T you are subject to data charges, and non-commercial use only. Any website for business or a personal website with any form of profit i.e would be in breach of there terms of usage.

This is why home businesses purchase business broadband. You best of asking them, after-all, its them who provide you with the service.

Comment: I would suspect that a commercial connection can be had from AT&T which is not too expensive. There are sometimes physical restrictions. Last week I checked going back to a commercial connection and it is a lot cheaper than what I have now. Silly cusses!! Commercial connections do not have the same restrictions of course. Some carriers do not care that you run your own services on a non-commercial line such as my carrier. There may be another carrier in the area worth checking.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a server (shadow IT) for HP a long time for "club India" to run some data pulls everyday. Never had an issue. Comcast aka Xfinity rarely in my experience changes their IP's and though they used to monitor traffic a lot- I found that to have dropped off at least with the hi end speed accounts.
Now if you have a lot of traffic- that could be another deal but if it's slight comapartively, I can't but help think you would be fine.

I worked there, I know how they did things at one time, and they are overloaded. You'd have to make a big foot print. Of course, if you have biz crucial stuff- never worth the risk.

Comment: I ran a personal web service on a Comcast/Xfinity residential connection several years back, not too dissimilar to this from a traffic shaping standpoint. They didn't care, IP address changes were extremely infrequent even though I had dynamic dns set up, and they didn't even bother to block ports 80 and 443, so I didn't bother changing them. I'm betting that their ToS clause is just CYA.